# HTML page id not printed same as being displayed

Tags: html, css, printing

i have a html page which has a table and whose header is not same when printed as is displayed
the green div tag and table footer text is just printed with no background
please help me
my code is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.cnt
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:21cm; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-top:0px; position:relative;">




<div style="width:90%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div style="color:#FFF; background-color:green; padding:5px; font:20px bolder Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:center;">
Receipt Details
</div>
<div>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#000" style="color:#FFF; text-align:center;">
<td>
Receipt No.
</td>
<td>
Date
</td>
<td>
Amount Paid
</td>
<td>
Amount Due
</td>
<td>
Remark
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align:center;">
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
500/-
</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
Registration
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align:center;">
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
Fee Payment
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align:center;">
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
Fee Payment
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align:center;">
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
Fee Payment
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>




</div>


</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Background colors and images are not printed by default in most browsers. Look for an option in the print dialog to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link href="/automin/90617406afeb35403b4c010c2cdd4071.css" type="text/css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, print">
```

Make sure your stylesheet is set to the `print` media.

Also, when you print, make sure "Print background colors is checked"

[image]